# CGContext: how do I erase pixels (e.g. kCGBlendModeClear) outside of a bitmap context?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm trying to build an eraser tool using Core Graphics, and I'm finding it incredibly difficult to make a performant eraser - it all comes down to:

`CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear)`

If you google around for how to "erase" with Core Graphics, almost every answer comes back with that snippet. The problem is it only (apparently) works in a bitmap context. If you're trying to implement interactive erasing, I don't see how `kCGBlendModeClear` helps you - as far as I can tell, you're more or less locked into erasing on and off-screen `UIImage`/`CGImage` and drawing that image in the famously non-performant `[UIView drawRect]`.

Here's the best I've been able to do:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (drawingStroke) {
        if (eraseModeOn) {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            [eraseImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
            CGContextAddPath(context, currentPath);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, ERASE_WIDTH);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
            curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        } else {
            [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextAddPath(context, currentPath);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }
    } else {
        [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }
}
```

Drawing a normal line (`!eraseModeOn`) is acceptably performant; I'm blitting my off-screen drawing buffer (`curImage`, which contains all previously drawn strokes) to the current `CGContext`, and I'm rendering the line (path) being currently drawn. It's not perfect, but hey, it works, and it's reasonably performant.

However, because `kCGBlendModeNormal` apparently does not work outside of a bitmap context, I'm forced to:

1. Create a bitmap context (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`).
2. Draw my offscreen buffer (`eraseImage`, which is actually derived from `curImage` when the eraser tool is turned on - so really pretty much the same as `curImage` for arguments sake).
3. Render the "erase line" (path) currently being drawn to the bitmap context (using `kCGBlendModeClear` to clear pixels).
4. Extract the entire image into the offscreen buffer (`curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`)
5. And then finally blit the offscreen buffer to the view's `CGContext`

That's horrible, performance-wise. Using Instrument's Time tool, it's painfully obvious where the problems with this method are:

- `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is expensive
- Drawing the offscreen buffer *twice* is expensive
- Extracting the entire image into an offscreen buffer is expensive

So naturally, the code performs horribly on a real iPad.

I'm not really sure what to do here. I've been trying to figure out how to clear pixels in a non-bitmap context, but as far as I can tell, relying on `kCGBlendModeClear` is a dead-end.

Any thoughts or suggestions? How do other iOS drawing apps handle erase?

---

**Additional Info**

I've been playing around with a `CGLayer` approach, as it does appear that `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear)` will work in a `CGLayer` based on a bit of googling I've done.

However, I'm not super hopeful that this approach will pan out. Drawing the layer in `drawRect` (even using `setNeedsDisplayInRect`) is hugely non-performant; Core Graphics is choking up will rendering each path in the layer in `CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint` (according to Instruments). As far as I can tell, using a bitmap context is definitely preferable here in terms of performance - the only problem, of course, being the above question (`kCGBlendModeClear` not working after I blit the bitmap context to the main `CGContext` in `drawRect`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to get good results by using the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (drawingStroke) {
        if (eraseModeOn) {
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(context, NULL);
            [eraseImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

            CGContextAddPath(context, currentPath);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, ERASE_WIDTH);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
            CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
        } else {
            [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextAddPath(context, currentPath);
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);
        }
    } else {
        [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }

    self.empty = NO;
}
```

The trick was to wrap the following into `CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer` / `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` calls:

- Blitting the erase background image to the context
- Drawing the "erase" path on top of the erase background image, using `kCGBlendModeClear`

Since both the erase background image's pixel data and the erase path are in the same layer, it has the effect of clearing the pixels.

Comment: this is the key line,`CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);`

Answer (score 2):

2D graphics following painting paradigms. When you are painting, it's hard to remove paint you've already put on the canvas, but super easy to add more paint on top. The blend modes with a bitmap context give you a way to do something hard (scrape paint off the canvas) with few lines of code. The few lines of code do not make it an easy computing operation (which is why it performs slowly).

The easiest way to fake clearing out pixels without having to do the offscreen bitmap buffering is to paint the background of your view over the image.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (drawingStroke) {
        CGColor lineCgColor = lineColor.CGColor;
        if (eraseModeOn) {
            //Use concrete background color to display erasing. You could use the backgroundColor property of the view, or define a color here
            lineCgColor = [[self backgroundColor] CGColor];
        } 
        [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextAddPath(context, currentPath);
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineCgColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    } else {
        [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    }
}
```

The more difficult (but more correct) way is to do the image editing on a background serial queue in response to an editing event. When you get a new action, you do the bitmap rendering in the background to an image buffer. When the buffered image is ready, you call `setNeedsDisplay` to allow the view to be redrawn during the next update cycle. This is more correct as `drawRect:` should be displaying the content of your view as quickly as possible, not processing the editing action.

```
@interface ImageEditor : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage * imageBuffer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
@end

@implementation ImageEditor

- (dispatch_queue_t) serialQueue
{
    if (_serialQueue == nil)
    {
        _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.com.imagebuffer", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return _serialQueue;
}

- (void)editingAction
{
    dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{
        CGSize bufferSize = [self.imageBuffer size];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bufferSize);

        CGContext context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, bufferSize.width, bufferSize.height), [self.imageBuffer CGImage]);

        //Do editing action, draw a clear line, solid line, etc

        self.imageBuffer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
        });
    });
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.imageBuffer drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
}

@end
```

Comment: So I've tried that before, without much luck (`[UIColor clearColor]') - though my blend mode setting was `kCBBlendModeClear`... I didn't try  `kCGBlendModeNormal` with that. I'll give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: Update - that does not work - it does not clear pixels that were drawn in the `[curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero]` call.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are doing wrong with all the ivars here. Other code may be setting `lineWidth` to 0.0 or `currentPath` may be uninitialized. The basic gist is the same though, just draw your line as with the clear (or background) color.

Comment: If I take out the ivars and explicitly set those values, I get the same result - no cleared pixels. `currentPath` is definitely initialized, because I can see it if I use a different color (e.g. `[UIColor greenColor]`).

The problem appears to be that I'm not drawing within a bitmap context - I'm just using the default context returned by `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` in `drawRect` - and therein lies my problem :-(

Comment: You are drawing transparency over top of opaque background, not actually altering the image. You 'see through' the line drawn when you use clearColor. You have to define what a background color looks like in the view using a concrete color and draw that. Updating answer

Comment: Right - but what I want to do is alter the image. The background of my drawing view is transparent already, because there will be content underneath it that needs show through (e.g., I'm building a drawing layer that sits on top of something). If I use an opaque background color for the eraser, I'm effectively obscuring everything below the drawing layer..

Comment: I guess what doesn't add up for me is this - I've drawn the image into the context already - why do further changes to that context not alter the drawn image data? Why do further changes (e.g., `CGContextStrokePath`) happen *on top* of the image data, instead of *to* the image data?

Comment: I understand that. The problem is you have already drawn in the context. You can't undraw. That's why the blend modes do the expensive bitmap buffer thing. You have to draw whatever should be behind your image on top of the image to avoid the expensive operation.

Comment: Check out the last half of the edited answer. I think part of the issue you are having with doing it natively is that you aren't subclassing UIView in the way it is intended. Editing the image and displaying the image are two different operations. `drawRect:` shouldn't be doing anything other than drawing to the context.

Comment: I think I've found a good alternative - see the answer I added to the question - the trick was to wrap the erase background image blit & path rendering in `CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer` / `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` calls.

Answer (score 1):

key is CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer and use clearColor and set         CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);